# Как правильно привести поля запроса к нужному типу?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-xe5

Использую TSQLQuery из библиотеки dbExpress

```
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select cast(0.001 as float)';
  SQLQuery1.Open;
  SQLQuery1.First;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsFloat));
```

В результате получаю:

> Exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Cannot access field 'Column0' as type Float'. Process Project1.exe (5888)

Зато поле без проблем считывается как String:

```
  Memo1.Lines.Add(SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsString);
```

Кстати, тоже самое получается после использования агрегатных функций, например:

```
select sum(amount) from table1 group by ....
```

несмотря на то что поле `amount` имеет вещественный тип, после калькуляции это поле в delphi можно считать только как `String`

Comment: Чему равно `SQLQuery1.Fields[0].ClassName`?

Comment: у вас какой нить `autofields` используется? или у запроса набор полей забит статически?

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения по поводу DecimalSeparator. Хотя по идее не должно такого быть...

Comment: @Anton `SQLQuery1.Fields[0].ClassName` возвращает `TWideMemoField`

Comment: @teran 'autofields' не используется, все запросы приведены в том виде как есть. Подобная проблема происходит со всеми данными которые вычисляются в запросах или которые не имеют прямой связи с данными в таблицах.

Comment: @kami если DecimalSeparator поменять на запятую то запрос уже не выполняется на стороне sqlite, так что с ним все в порядке.

Comment: `TWideMemoField` говорит о том, что DBX не может вытащить тип поля.  Попробуйте пройтись отладчиком по `TCustomSQLDataSet.InternalInitFieldDefs`

Comment: дак `SQLQuery1` это компонент на форме? у него `columns` заполнено что-либо? Я конечно давно не работал с delphi и с БД в нем, но там вроде либо поля автоматчески создаются, либо забиты статично. Если у вас автоматом отключено, то значит статика и неправильным типом

Comment: попробуйте динамически запрос создать, и выполнить.

Comment: @teran как я писал выше, TSQLQuery компонент из библиотеки dbExpress, помещен на форму, но запрос как раз у меня формируется динамически, никакие свойства этого компонента не заполняются, едиственно в Object Inspector'e указано свойство SQLConnection - > SQLConnection1 компонент из той же библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Так как все данные не имеющие прямой связи с таблицами возвращаются в строчном виде, то что бы решить свою задачу был вынужден динамически создавать временную таблицу, записывать в нее данные и считывать их от туда уже с нужным типом. 
В случае запросов с агрегатными функциями решение выглядит так:

```
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
  'drop table if exists temp.agregatetable1;      ';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(False);
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
  'create temp table if not exists AgregateTable1 '+
  '(                                              '+
  '  [OrderNumber] integer,                       '+
  '  [SumAmount] float                            '+
  ');                                             ';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(False);
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
  'insert into Temp.AgregateTable1                '+
  'select                                         '+
  '     OrderNumber,                              '+
  '     sum(Amount)                               '+
  'from                                           '+
  '     Table1                                    '+
  'group by                                       '+
  '      OrderNumber;                             ';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL(False);
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 
  'select SumAmount from Temp.AgregateTable1      ';
  SQLQuery1.Open;
  SQLQuery1.First;
  while not SQLQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStr(SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).AsFloat));
      SQLQuery1.Next;
    end;
```

Если кто-то знает решение лучше, буду рад если поделитесь им.

Comment: А что мешает использовать     SQLQuery1.Fields.FieldByNumber(1).Value? И проверять VarIsInt, например.